# Select the row with the maximum value of specific column In MySQL using pymysql

Tags: mysql

I have this table.

| id | temp | hum | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 | 32 | 2012 |
| 2 | 37 | 44 | 2017 |

How can I select the max value in temp and it's date? So these two values(37, 2017).I am using PyMySql in python.

Comment: What `MySQL` version are you using ?

Comment: Not sure of this but I think 10.3.34-MariaDB

Comment: You can be sure by running this query: `show global variables like 'version%';`

Answer (score 0):

In `MySQL 8+` you can use [ROW_NUMBER](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-row_number-function/)

```
with cte as 
      (   select *,
                   row_number() over( order by temp desc ) row_num
          from your_table
       ) select id, temp,hum,date
         from cte 
         where row_num=1;
```

Another solution:

```
Select id,temp,hum,date
from your_table
order by temp desc limit 1;
```